# Python error importing module pandas "name 'GET' is not defined"

Tags: python, pandas, installation, package

I have the most updated numpy, httplib2, pytz, Cython, python-dateutil & numexpr

And newest pandas build

But I'm flummoxed! The following code gives the following rather cryptic error. What is it trying to tell me?

```
import pandas
print "ok pandas"
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sank.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.14.1-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/pandas/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from pandas.io.api import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.14.1-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/pandas/io/api.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pandas.io.gbq import read_gbq
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.14.1-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/pandas/io/gbq.py", line 59, in <module>
    import httplib2
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2-0.9-py2.7.egg/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1070, in <module>
    from google.appengine.api import apiproxy_stub_map
  File "/Users/maggielee/Documents/pythons/google.py", line 32, in <module>
    GET / HTTP/1.0
NameError: name 'GET' is not defined
```

Comment: Error is in `line 32` in file `google.py` - see this line in code.

Comment: You can rename file `google.py` - probably python uses this file when it imports `from google.appengine.api`

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by furas and OP.*

I had an old file called `google.py`. Just renamed/deleted it and problem was solved.

Probably python uses this file when it imports `from google.appengine.api`.